# how can I insert own svg icons into ionic 6?

Tags: ionic-framework, svg, icons

Hello how are you? I've been trying to insert my own icons into svg for days, I've seen several blogs but they don't work for me. I'm using ionic version
6.12.2. Does anyone know how I can insert my own svg icons ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! Ionic 6 was not release yet, so I guess that's the CLI version. You can run `ionic info` and you'd see that there's a version for the `Ionic CLI` and another version for `Ionic Framework `. The later is the version of Ionic that you're using (I guess it's Ionic 5.X.X). Greetings from another argentino :)

Comment: Gracias Seba ! PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\App-Loggapp\LoggApp-APP> ionic version 
6.12.2  Me figura eso, por eso pense que era la 6, perdón soy muy nueva en el tema. De nuevo muchas gracias !

Comment: No worries! It can be a bit confusing at first :) Feel free to try the answers and if any of them works you can mark it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using a SASS mixin was a common way to do this in Ionic 3, but in Ionic 4/5 it's much much simpler. Like you can see in the **[Ionicons docs](https://ionicons.com/usage)**:

> **Custom icons**
>
> To use a custom SVG, provide its url in the src attribute to request the external SVG file. The src attribute works the same as  in that the url must be accessible from the webpage that's making a request for the image. Additionally, the external file can only be a valid svg and does not allow scripts or events within the svg element.

```
<ion-icon src="/path/to/external/file.svg"></ion-icon>
```

So for example you can put your own icons folder in the `assets` folder, like this:

```
src
  |- app
  |- ...
  |- assets
      |- icons
          |- user.svg
          |- ...
```

Which can be used then like this:

```
 <ion-icon src="assets/icons/user.svg"></ion-icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Sass properties to handle my icons.

In my `styles` folder, I have a class like `_icons-svg.scss`, and a class named `_mixins.scss`

In my `_icons-svg.scss` :

```
.icon-svg {
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  background-size: 100% 100% !important;
  &.my-first-svg {
    @include svg-icon('my-first-svg-icon');
    height: 22px;
    width: 12px;
  }
  &.my-second-svg {
    @include svg-icon('my-second-svg-icon');
    height: 22px;
    width: 12px;
  }
...
```

And in my `_mixins.scss` file, I have :

```
@mixin svg-icon($icon-name) {
  background: url('src/assets/icons/svg/' + $icon-name + '.svg') no-repeat;
}
```

So replace in the url by the folder containing your svg files.
So my svg file looks like this in my svg folder :

```
my-first-svg-icon.svg
my-second-svg-icon.svg
```

And then on my HTML I just have to call like this :

```
<div class="icon-svg my-second-svg"></div>
```